# Group list of dictionaries by value

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries. How can i group that list by valaues.

```
list = [{a:1},{b:2},{c:1},{d:3},{e:2}]
```

Now my result should be like below

```
1:a,c
2:b,e
3:d
```

I tried using `groupby` from `itertools`. But i couldn't get the required result. I am using python 2.7.

Could you help me achieve this?

Comment: can you post the `groupby` code you tried?

Comment: Don't name things like builtin types (`list`), that can have bad side effects. Now, you can either go the "how can I use `itertools.groupby`" way or you could roll your own. In either case, you will have to be much more specific in your question and also show some effort. Remember, nobody here is going to do your homework for you.

Comment: Goupby only works if the data is sorted by the same key function, so sort first.

Comment: Also, why do you have a list of dicts, each having a single, unique key? Can't you just have a single dict?

Comment: This feels like a `defaultdict` type issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use `groupby`, the list has to be `sorted` by the same key you want to group by.

```
>>> lst = [{'a':1}, {'b':2}, {'c':1}, {'d':3}, {'e':2}]

>>> keyfunc = lambda d: next(iter(d.values()))

>>> sorted(lst, key=keyfunc)
[{'a': 1}, {'c': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'e': 2}, {'d': 3}]

>>> {k: [x for d in g for x in d] 
...  for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(lst, key=keyfunc), key=keyfunc)}
{1: ['a', 'c'], 2: ['b', 'e'], 3: ['d']}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a possible solution without using any library.

```
def get_dict(list):
    res = {}

    for elem in list:
        k, v = elem.keys(), elem.values()

        if v[0] in res:
            res[v[0]].append(k[0])
        else:
            res[v[0]] = [k[0]]

    return res
```

With a list like yours, this would output a dictionary with the following format:

```
{ 1:[a,c], 2:[b, e], 3:[c] }
```

This is considering you're always going to have the same format as input. If not, you could just adjust what is read and saved.

Answer (score 2):

This might help.

```
list = [{"a":1},{"b":2},{"c":1},{"d":3},{"e":2}]
d = {}
for i in list:
    key, value = i.items()[0]
    if value not in d:
        d[value] = [key]
    else:
        d[value].append(key)
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
{1: ['a', 'c'], 2: ['b', 'e'], 3: ['d']}
```

**Tested in python2.7**

Comment: Fails in Py 3..

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: Well I haven't tried it but you can't index `dict_items`, of course `next(iter())` syntax is possible

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do what you are looking for:

```
list_ = [{"a":1},{"b":2},{"c":1},{"d":3},{"e":2}]
values = set(value for dic in list_ for value in dic.values())

for value in values:
  keys = [list(dic.keys())[0] for dic in list_ if value in dic.values()]
  print("{}: {}".format(value, keys))
```

Output:

```
1: ['a', 'c']
2: ['b', 'e']
3: ['d']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses `defaultdict`.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 1}, {'d': 3}, {'e': 2}]
d = defaultdict(list)

for l in lst:
    val, key = l.items()[0]
    d[key].append(val)

print(d)
```

Output:
`defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: ['a', 'c'], 2: ['b', 'e'], 3: ['d']})`